# How to edit raw android gesture file on windows or linux

Tags: android, linux, windows, gesture

So, I used the GestureBuilder Activity in Android to make some gesture files to use.

I was wondering if I can edit or at least view the contents of the gesture file in windows or linux with some tool, be it eclipse or something. I tired to do simple things like changing the file format to .zip or .tar to see if maybe they were simple archived files with a set of PNG files defining the gestures, but they did not work.

It would be great to be able to play around them and edit the content of the gesture file easily while not just on the mobile device. ESP since I want to try and see what gestures work best and compare having a low number of gestures vs high and compare combos (IE having both box and rectangle confuses the system, while having just one of each mixed in with others works well enough) and their effectiveness when comparing their prediction score.

On other note, if anyone know of some good gestures that limits both false positive and false negative, that would be appreciated to get me started more on this research that is going slow due to how hard it is to reset and select gestures to compare with.

Thanks.